# Django with docker doesn't run custom app's migrations

Tags: python, django, docker, django-migrations

I have create a custom app named `bay` in my project's root directory, structure looks like below -

```
project_root/  
   - bay/
       - migrations/
           - __init__.py
           - 0001_initial.py
       - models/
           - __init__.py
           - document.py
           - ... (other model files)
```

When I am trying to save a new model instance from one of my custom app's models, I get the following error -

```
postgres_1  | ERROR:  relation "bay_brand" does not exist at character 13
postgres_1  | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "bay_brand" ("name") VALUES ('xyz') RETURNING "bay_brand"."id"
```

Thus, the migration for the given model hasn't been run. So, I try to migrate with -

```
sudo docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py migrate
```

which results in

```
Postgres is up - continuing...
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, socialaccount, users
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying users.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying sites.0003_set_site_domain_and_name... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0001_initial... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0002_token_max_lengths... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0003_extra_data_default_dict... OK
  Applying users.0002_auto_20170419_1104... OK
```

The above clearly does not show the `bay.0001_initial` migration it should have run. So, I go ahead and see the output of

```
sudo docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py makemigrations bay
```

which results in

```
Postgres is up - continuing...
Migrations for 'bay':
  bay/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Brand
    - Create model ...
    - ...
```

And if I try to run the `migrate` command again, it says `No migrations to apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was a file permissions issue, was seeing the lock symbols on the `__init__.py` file and `__pycache__` folders in my `migrations` folder. Had ignored it initially since it was similar to the one in my existing app's `migrations` folder but those migrations did run nicely.

Deleted the `migrations` folder in my custom app, ran `makemigrations` command and then `migrate` successfully -

```
Postgres is up - continuing...
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, bay, contenttypes, sessions, sites, socialaccount, users
Running migrations:
  Applying bay.0001_initial... OK
```